# Corda - Explicit Contract Upgrades

Tags: corda

R3's official Corda [documentation](https://docs.corda.net/contract-upgrade.html) states that...

> Bank B initiates the upgrade flow, which will send an upgrade proposal
>   to all contract participants. Each of the participants of the contract
>   state will sign and return the contract state upgrade proposal once
>   they have validated and agreed with the upgrade. The upgraded
>   transaction will be recorded in every participant’s node by the flow.

```
val rpcClient : CordaRPCClient = << Bank B's Corda RPC Client >>
val rpcB = rpcClient.proxy()
rpcB.startFlow({ stateAndRef, upgrade -> ContractUpgradeFlow(stateAndRef, upgrade) },
    <<StateAndRef of the contract state>>,
    DummyContractV2::class.java)
```

After executing the `ContractUpgradeFlow` should I expect to see a consumed V1 state and a newly created V2 state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After executing the ContractUpgradeFlow should I expect to see a consumed V1 state and a newly created V2 state?

Yes, that is correct.